# CalendarExtender loose his value on postback

Tags: postback, calendarextender

Here is the code of my date selecting control. 
When the page containing the control is submitted AFTER the Page_Load and link button click events passed,  tb is reset to it is initial value (which is today)

```
<div class="ui-form-text">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ce" runat="server" TargetControlID="tb" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
    CssClass="calendar" EnableViewState="true">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="mee" runat="server" TargetControlID="tb" Enabled="true"
    Mask="99\/99\/9999" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" EnableViewState="true">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb" Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Невалидна дата" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb" Type="Date">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem myself and the only solution (well, workaround) I could find was this:

[ASP.NET Ajax CalendarExtender will not update SelectedDate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621112/asp-net-ajax-calendarextender-will-not-update-selecteddate-value)

Comment: While this is helpful, linking to another SO question isn't an acceptable answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can  help you, this worked for me.

---

```
String tmp_;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request[txtCalendarExtender.UniqueID] != null)
            {
                if (Request[txtCalendarExtender.UniqueID].Length > 0)
                {
                    this.tmp_ = Request[txtCalendarExtender.UniqueID];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```